# SSH - Match Address removed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I was delighted to find out that SSH config files allow you to specify configurations with the `Match` condition, including by `Address` as I was hoping. Unfortunately, it's not working.

My first red flag was that vim was not highlighting `Address` like it was for the `Host` and `User` conditions. Then, when I tested this configuration:

```
Match Address x.x.x.x
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

with [shellinabox](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox), I got this error:

```
/home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Bad Match condition
```

I searched around for documentation and web articles for mentions of the `Address` condition. Most of the sources I found were years old making me think it was removed recently, except for [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/match-address-sshd_config-allow-root-loginfrom-one_ip_address-on-linux-unix/) which was posted just over two months ago. Obviously, the article was written with old/bad info, but I would still like to know why `Address` is a `Bad condition`, as I have yet to find a working alternative.

If this is related to the issue: I'm working with an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Match Address x.x.x.x

`Match Address` is usable only in the `sshd_config` (server). The `ssh_config` (client config) has the `Match Host` or just `Host` keyword

Comment: Do you know why it's like this?

Comment: The match block in client and server were probably implemented at different times so little bit different naming was chosen. Or it can be intentional so you will not write server configuration options to the client one and vice versa (thought there are already many common options).

Comment: Thanks for all the help and quick responses!